# I try to get a border around the header with CSS using ID. But the border will not show?

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML coding and it is this main header that I want to have a border around.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,300&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  margin: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#main-header {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="main header">
    <h1>Best news ever!</h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

I hope someone can see what I do wrong.

Comment: You don't have a dash in your html. Needs to be `id="main-header"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your HTML markup the opening `body` tag isn't being closed properly and your `<header id="main-header"` is missing a hyphen `-` should look like the below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,300&display=swap');
body {
    font-family:"Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-weight:300 !important;
    margin:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body h1 {
  font-weight:300;
}


 #main-header {
      border: 1px solid #000;

}
```

```html
 <body>
<header id="main-header">
<h1>Best news ever!</h1>
</header>
</body>
```